# Master-Detail Create Views with Razor, ASP.NET MVC 3 and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm new to .NET all together, please be patient with me if I have any silly mistakes.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3 with .NET 4.0

I want to have a *"Create"* view for a model that has a child Model. This view should include the child model's ***partial*** *"Create"* view, I'll use the following simple example for illustration purposes:

- The **Person** model

  ```
  class Person
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public Address { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- The **Address** model

  ```
  class Address
  {
      public string City { get; set; }
      public string Zip { get; set; }

      //A List for creating a <select/> item in the view
      //containing cities fetched from the database.
      //The initialization is done in the controller action returning
      //the related partial view.
      public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CityDropDown { get; set; } )
  }
  ```
- The Controller Actions

  ```
      class MyController : Controller
      {
          public ViewResult Create()
          {
              var person = new Person();
              var address = new Address();
              // initialization of address.CityDropDown omitted
              person.Address = address;
              return View(MyViews.CreatePersonView, person);
          }

          [HttpPost]
          public ViewResult Create(Person person)
          {
              //persistance logic
          }
      }
  ```
- The views hierarchy I want to have :

[image: Person Create View Hierarchy]

The solutions that I have tried in order to achieve this are the following :

### First approach : Using `@Html.Partial(..)` or `@{Html.RenderPartial(..)}`

---

#### What I did :

- The **Person** view

  ```
  @model Person
  @using(Html.BeginForm()){
      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name)
      @Html.Partial(MyViews.AddressPartialView, @Model.Address)
  }
  ```
- The **Address** partial view

  ```
  @model Address
  @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Zip)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.City, @Model.CityDropDown)
  ```

#### The problem :

When submitting the form, `person.Address` is null. After a bit of searching on Google, I found out that in order for the submit of the address field to work, the generated HTML markup must be the following (notice the `Address_` prefix) :

```
<form...>
    <input type=text id="Name" />
    <input type=text id="Address_Zip" />
    <select id="Address_City">
        <!-- options... -->
    </select>
</form>
```

Needless to say, the generated HTML markup in my case isn't the same but instead it's the following (the `Address_` prefix is missing) :

```
<form...>
    <input type=text id="Name" />
    <input type=text id="Zip" />
    <select id="City">
        <!-- options... -->
    </select>
</form>
```

### Second approach : Using an *EditorTemplate* for the Address model

---

#### What I did :

- I moved the **Address** partial view to the folder ***View/Shared/EditorTemplates*** assuring that it has the same name as the `Address` property in the `Person` model, i.e ***Address.cshtml***.
- The **Person** view

  ```
  @model Person
  @using(Html.BeginForm()){
      @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Name)
      @Html.EditorFor(@Model.Address) //will automatically find the Address 
                               //partial view in the EditorTemplates folder
  }
  ```

#### The problem :

Using this approach the generated markup has in fact the proper prefix (i.e. `Address_`), but I get an ***Object reference not set to an instance exception*** for the `Address.CityDropDown` property which tells me that the pre-initialised Address object in the controller's action isn't passed to the partial view for some reason.

### Third approach : put all Address fields in the Person model

---

This approach works with no problems, but I don't want to use it as I don't want to have redundant code if I ever want to have a create view for address in another model.

### To sum up

---

What should I do in order to have a **reusable** partial create view that I can use accross my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had the correct approach with EditorTemplates, but keep in mind you need to populate the `CityDropDown`. So, the view should be handed off something like:

```
Person model = new Person()
{
    Address = new Address
    {
        CityDropDown = new SelectListItem[]{
            new SelectListItem { Selected = true, Text = "Select one..." },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Anywhere", Value = "Anywhere" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Somewhere", Value = "Somewhere" },
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Nowhere", Value = "Nowhere" }
        }
    }
};
```

Which would then make this view only consist of:

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

And then your `EditorTemplates` would pick up from there:

**~/Views/shared/EditorTemplates/Address.cshtml** (Note: this is based on *type* not property name)

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Address
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.City, Model.CityDropDown)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Zip)
```

**~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication.Models.Person
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

the three views then render something like:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
  <input class="text-box single-line" id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="" />
  <select id="Address_City" name="Address.City">
    <option selected="selected">Select one...</option>
    <option value="Anywhere">Anywhere</option>
    <option value="Somewhere">Somewhere</option>
    <option value="Nowhere">Nowhere</option>
  </select>
  <input class="text-box single-line" id="Address_Zip" name="Address.Zip" type="text" value="" />
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

Example project can be found here: https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/master/questions-19247958

Comment: It's very generous of you to create a whole project as an answer, Thank you. In my case, I do in fact populate the CityDropDown as I should. The weird thing is that in the parent view while debugging, I can see that Model.Address is properly initialized and CityDropDown is populated, but when the cursor goes to the partial view, the Model is null. This doesn't happen in the project you made but only in mine.

Comment: @K-SaMa: did you provide the `@model` directive in your EditorTemplate (for `Address`)?

Comment: yes of course, I'm now really lost as to what might be the problem exactly.

Comment: @K-SaMa: has to be a configuration option somewhere. If it works on a vanilla MVC, it has to be something misconfigured or unsupplied in your project.

Comment: @K-SaMa: If you find things like that happening frequently, make sure to clean your solution (right click and choose "Clean") before going too far down the diagnostic road. a lot of times it can be due to library reference mis-matches or cached dependencies.